# Assertion failed DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm working on a DirectX 11 project and keep getting this error:

[image: here the image]

It says that error occurs in model.cpp file which my teacher sent me. Line 400: assert(file);

```
void CModel::LoadMaterial( const char *FileName, MODEL_MATERIAL **MaterialArray, unsigned int *MaterialNum )
{

char dir[MAX_PATH];
strcpy(dir, FileName);
PathRemoveFileSpec(dir);



char str[256];

FILE *file;
file = fopen( FileName, "rt" );
assert(file);

MODEL_MATERIAL *materialArray;
unsigned int materialNum = 0;
```

Or maybe I should send the whole model.cpp file to see why there is that Runtime Error?

Comment: Don't use ``assert`` for error handling. It's for validating working code, but you should have some kind of error detection here even when building for Release instead of Debug. A [fast-fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) error like throwing a C++ exception is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the FileName file exists.  The assert is being thrown because the file object is null (0) as the call to fopen failed.